# What's the correct way of accessing Scala tuple elements in Java?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I noticed that I can acces the elements from a Scala `Tuple` in Java by either using the field (e.g. `_1`) or a method (e.g. `_1()`). Is there a "better" way of doing this for any reason (technical, canon …)?

Comment: I've marked as a duplicate since the related question shows how to 'unapply' a tuple and assign vars to each tuple field. I can reopen if people don't think this is a duplicate

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate. This question is about using Scala tuples in Java, and the original question is about using tuples in Scala.

Comment: Not (yet) sure how this is a duplicate. For context: I'm writing a Spark Application in Java. Therefore I often have to interact with Scala Tuples. I noticed that there are two ways to acces there elements. Since I want my code to be consistent I'm looking for the 'right' way (or at least convention) how to do this. The other questions seems to be about avoiding to use this cumbersome notation while programming in scala.

Comment: My apologies. I've re-opened since I didn't notice the Java specificity (in fact I expected merely to nominate for closure, rather than actually *close* it)

Comment: To perhaps answer your question, I suspect there *isn't* another way to do this, and perhaps you should map to a case class prior to exposing to Java, to avoid the unfriendly _1() style methods you otherwise need to make

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you analyse the definition of `Tuple2` in the standard library:

```scala
final case class Tuple2[@specialized(Int, Long, Double, Char, Boolean/*, AnyRef*/) +T1, @specialized(Int, Long, Double, Char, Boolean/*, AnyRef*/) +T2](_1: T1, _2: T2)
  extends Product2[T1, T2]
```

If you replicate this definition into your own `MyTuple2` and look at the bytecode, you will indeed notice that `_1` and `_2` are declared as public fields. However, if you remove the `@specialized` annotation on a field, the field becomes private, like for any regular case class. I could not find any information on why this happens, but it is probably out there deep in the Scala compiler doc. The field becomes public if the annotation is there, even if it is empty and no specialized types are specified.

So I would stay, stick with the methods `_1()` and `_2()` to be safe.